# Why cant I download R tools

Tags: r, rtools

(disclamer : i am a complete newbie in R)
I am trying to install library("psych") for my class but for that I have to install Rtools.
I followed the instructions and downloaded the program, then put the code

```
writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

into the console just as the website said.
However, the code keeps coming up as an error.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You don't *need* Rtools to install the psych library unless you want to install it from source. Nor should you have to do anything using writeLines - configuration should be automatic. What is the error that you see?

Comment: Rtools is only needed for installation *from source on Windows OS*, but Windows packages already have binaries available for download. See the page of [`pschy` on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=psych), there's an entry *Windows binaries*.

Comment: I... honestly don't know. The professor at my university instructed us to download the psych library but when i typed the install.packages("psych") it asked if I wished to download it on a private file so I did (on one drive) but then said that I couldn't install it due to it being an "invalid argument" and I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: can you upload a picture when you try to run the install.packages("psych"), what error did you get? because mine works perfectly